# Can I use python Template to recursively use a dictionary as its own template to replace values in the source dictionary

Tags: python, templates

I would like to use a dictionary as its own template.

My attempt is below.  Actual I used AI to get that function but AI was unable to
generalize.

```
def recursive_template(d, **kwargs):
    d.update(kwargs)
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, str):
            try:
                template = Template(v)
                d[k] = template.substitute(**kwargs)
            except KeyError:
                pass
        elif isinstance(v, dict):  # added condition to handle nested dictionaries
            d[k] = recursive_template(v, **kwargs)
    return d

config_dict = {
    'dataPath': '/home/work/Users/',
    'dataLoc': '${dataPath}inst/extdata/'
}
config_dict2 = recursive_template(d=config_dict
print(config_dict2)
```

Wanted

```
{'dataPath': '/home/work/Users/',
 'dataLoc': '/home/work/Users/inst/extdata/}'}
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the solution, but other people more knowledgeable than me might have something better:

```
def recursive_template(d, **kwargs):
    d.update(kwargs)
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, str):
            try:
                template = Template(v)
                d[k] = template.substitute(**d)
            except KeyError:
                pass
        elif isinstance(v, dict):  # added condition to handle nested dictionaries
            d[k] = recursive_template(v, **d)
    return d

config_dict = {
    'dataPath': '/home/hnelson3/work/Users/hnelson3/',
    'dataLoc': '${dataPath}inst/extdata/'
}
config_dict2 = recursive_template(d=config_dict, today=date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
print(config_dict2)
{'dataPath': '/home/hnelson3/work/Users/hnelson3/',
 'dataLoc': '/home/hnelson3/work/Users/hnelson3/inst/extdata/}',
 'today': '2023-02-21'}
```

```
{'dataPath': '/home/hnelson3/work/Users/hnelson3/', 'dataLoc': '/home/hnelson3/work/Users/hnelson3/inst/extdata/', 'today': '2023-02-21'}
```